# Backward compatibility for IDL/ODL

Tags: backwards-compatibility, idl, visual-studio-6

Can anyone tell where I can read on the IDL defined by Microsoft.
I need to know about changing the IDL file by adding new members to interfaces. I have some confusion about maintaining the backward compatibility.

I am programming in VS6 (ActiveX programming).

Thanks in advance.

Datte

Answer (score 1):

Try to read these articles:

- [Changing Interfaces in a Backward Compatible Manner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Examples of Incompatible Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)